# How can i detect if i'm in an app or i'm in a browser on android with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, browser

i'm trying to write a Javascript code that identifies if i'm seeing a site from a browser or from an app with a web view.
I know that i can use the userAgent to check on which OS (in this case Android) i'm running the site in the form of

```
if (userAgent.includes("Android")){
// do something
}
```

But what if i want to split this categorization in App View and Browser View?

Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Generally speaking user agent sniffing is something you want to avoid, it's often faked to prevent fingerprinting etc.  You really should be using some form feature detection if your wanting this to render differently on different devices.

Comment: Is it your own app? If yes you can add functions that are provided by the app that are callable by the JavaScript code running in the WebView. If those functions are available your can be sure you are in your app (or at least in an app).

Comment: I do not have direct access to the app, i can only inject some js to the site and return some values. So maybe the answer above is the best for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell if your site is being viewed in a regular browser or in an app's web view, check `navigator.userAgent` for "Android" and specific indicators like "wv" or "WebView". These clues help differentiate between browser and app views, like solving a small puzzle!

```
if (navigator.userAgent.includes("Android")) {
    if (navigator.userAgent.includes("wv") || navigator.userAgent.includes("WebView")) {
        console.log("Viewing in App (WebView)");
    } else {
        console.log("Viewing in Browser");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cann`t we use screen resolution with user agent to identify if this is running on mobile ?

Comment: Can I use the same code also for iOS (changing the first condition evalutation obv)?